# How to set default combobox value to the value set in Properties file?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am writing script to display properties file using swing. On UI, there is a combobox:

```
private JComboBox Types= new JComboBox();
```

I have set 3 values to it as below:

```
private String[] Options = { "Web", "IOS", "Android" };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    Types.addItem(Options[count++]);
```

The default value set is Web. I need to read config.prop file and set the default value of the combobox to the value set in config.prop file. For eg. if value set in config.prop is Type=IOS, combobox should display IOS.

I have tried below method, but the combobox shows blank:

```
Types.setSelectedItem(configProp.getProperty("Type"));
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: BTW - you realise it is capitalized as iOS, not IOS, right?

Comment: you can first check what is returned by : `int index = Arrays.asList(Options).indexOf( configProp.getProperty("Type"));` If index is not -1, then sure it is there in list, then you can `Types.setSelectedIndex( index );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know your problem. you are using count in your loop. use 'i'

```
private String[] Options = { "Web", "IOS", "Android" };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    Types.addItem(Options[i]);

int index = Arrays.asList( Options ).indexOf( configProp.getProperty("Type") );
if ( index != -1 )
{
   Types.setSelectedIndex(index);
}
else if( Options.length() > 0 )
{
   Types.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am able to set the value of combo box with this code.

Answer (score 0):

As the JcomboBox is list of String, It should be already working fine. Can you check the value of

```
configProp.getProperty("Type")
```